# NestJS pass downloaded file straight to client

Tags: node.js, axios, nestjs

I have a situation when a client React app is requesting a file from a NestJS server. NestJS is getting this file from another API so uses the HttpService to get it. I don't want the Nest application to save this file I just want to send it straight to the client, I'm having trouble doing this. I have tried:

```
return this.http
            .get(
                '[downloadURL]', this.options
            ).pipe(map(res => res.data));
```

but that strips off all the files information, like name and extension (it's a zip).

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

This code worked for me

```
@Get()
async redirectFile(@Res() res: Response) { 
    let url = 'https://sample.org/file.pdf';
    let response = await this.httpService.axiosRef(url, {
      responseType: 'stream',
    });
    response.data.pipe(res);
}
```

if you are working behind a corporate http proxy, request to https url may hang, in this case you can use https-proxy-agent

```
import { HttpsProxyAgent } from 'https-proxy-agent';

@Get()
async redirectFile(@Res() res: Response) { 
    let url = 'https://sample.org/file.pdf';
    let agent = new HttpsProxyAgent('http://host:port');
    let response = await this.httpService.axiosRef(url, {
      httpsAgent: agent,
      responseType: 'stream',
    });
    response.data.pipe(res);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       res.on('finish', resolve);
       res.on('error', reject);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
@Get(':id/download')
    async exportDownload(
        @Param('id') id: number,
        @Res() res: Response
    ){
       res.set("Content-Type","application/zip");
       res.set("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=file.zip");
       let zip = await this.http
            .get(
                '[downloadURL]', this.options
            ).pipe(map(res => res.data));
       res.end(zip);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

For anyone passing, this is the solution:

```
@Get(':id/download')
    exportDownload(
        @Param('id') id: number,
        @Res() res: Response
    ): Observable<any> {
        return this.apiService.downloadExport(id).pipe(
            map(response => response.data.pipe(res))
        );
    }
```

Comment: what does downloadExport(id) do?